# Runtime.exec with absolute value?

Tags: java, string, runtime

I have:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec ("Rscript "+ hallo +""),
```

where "hallo" is a String containing the absolute path to the script.

This, however, does not work in that the exitValue is 2, so the file is not found.
Is there a way to pass a String object to Runtime.exec?

Edit:

Found a way by simply passing "Rscript" + hallo.

However, I still get an exitValue of 2. How is that possible? I know the absolute Path is right because I got it via file.getAbsolutePath.

Comment: If this is Java 5 or higher, don't use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`; use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: What is the underlying platform that this code is being executed on?

Comment: please paste your file path here... I think if there is a space in your file path then you should use double quote to bind file path when executing the code.